# validating the value in a integer...?

Tags: c++, c

how do v find a value in an integer is garbage or not???

Comment: Integer variables cannot contain garbage, only integers.

Comment: Not a meaningful question. One man's garbage is another man's data. There's no values that an integer can hold that are not potentially meaningful.

Comment: Give any example of any garbage value in integer.

Comment: As most programmers know, 205688 is the garbage-constant, so simply check with `i == 205688`.

Comment: Perhaps you are thinking as a Garbage Collector, 

so when you don't need it anymore, it's garbage!

Example

        int i;    
    
        /*count to three*/
    
        for(i=1;i<=3;i++)
        {
           printf("\r\n Counting %d",i);
        }    
    
        /*now if you won't use i again,*/ 
        /*you can consider it garbage.*/


As you can't throw it away, you can **reuse it**, if you were a compiler, you would.

Answer (score 8):

Initialize it at point of declaration, and it can never be garbage.

Comment: +1, another C++ coding standard

Comment: hey, i never said you should _always_ do it. it just solves the OP's problem.

Comment: Just make sure the value you initialize it with isn't... oh no!

Comment: This isn't entirely true... if you fail to initialize some other integer and assign that to your first integer, then it might have a garbage value.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Pass it to [strfry](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/strfry.html) and compare the returned value with the original.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you mean if a string contains a valid integer. Check out scanf or the stream equivalent of c++, or [Boost lexical cast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/conversion/lexical_cast.htm#lexical_cast)